# input tags not working with angular directive (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```js
var app = angular.module("myDiscuss", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('PageController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.showModalTag = false;
  $scope.opentag = function() {
    $scope.showModalTag = !$scope.showModalTag;
  };
});

app.directive('tagmodal', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
      '<div class="modal-content">' +
      '<div class="modal-header">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
      '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.title = attrs.title;

      scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value) {
        if (value == true)
          $(element).modal('show');
        else
          $(element).modal('hide');
      });

      $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
        });
      });

      $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  < href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/custom.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src=https://curofy-static.s3.amazonaws.com/web/js/typeahead.js></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body ng-app="myDiscuss">
  <div ng-controller="PageController">
    <tagmodal title="Edit Tags" visible="showModalTag">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput"></input>
        </div>
      </form>
    </tagmodal>
  </div>
  <a ng-click="opentag()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color:#009b86"></span>open it</a>
</body>

</html>
```

When the input tag is placed in the tagmodal it does not work.
whereas if we put it out of the modal it is working fine
i don't get it why is it not working inside the tagmodal. is there some library is to be included or is it because of the angular

here is the link of plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/o0BruX9oRRr0Lo5yNXIF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that

`<tagmodal>` is actually a template and it's set of some html tags. you cannot add another html code inside `<tagmodal>` from the html.

ie., you are not allowed to add

```
<form role ="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" value="html" data-role="tagsinput"/>
    </div>  
</form>
```

inside `<tagmodal>`

you can add the html portion inside the template in the directive code(inside js)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, since you are using angular js, the `input` element within the modal might get created after the dom ready event(on which the `tagsinput` plugin is automatically initialized in input/select elements with `data-role=tagsinput`).

The angularjs way to do this is to use a directive which can initialize the plugin like

```
<tagmodal title ="Edit Tags" visible="showModalTag">
    <form role ="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" value="html" tagsinput/>
            </div>  
    </form>
</tagmodal>
```

then

```
app.directive('tagsinput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element){
      $element.tagsinput();
    }
  }
})
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rTOZt1KctiBPGhMKJRuc?p=preview)